# How do I comment out a line in .pro files?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am trying to use Qt Creator. How do I comment out a line or create comments in a .pro file? Thanks.

Comment: `some_configuration # some comment`, that's what you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Select the line(s) in your `.pro` file that you want to comment.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

OR,

Manually put `#` before the line(s).

Answer (score 4):

just enter a `#` at line beginning